# Object method not working inside object but does outside?

Tags: java, oop, object

I've been making a linkedlist program that uses node objects that simply contain an int and a reference to the next node. One of the methods I've been trying to implement within the list class is linking one list already made to the last element of another list, thus 'linking' them to each other so that it is one long chain of nodes fused together.

However, even though all of my syntax is correct it's quite odd to me that the following method is not working for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//main program
LinkedListHT lst1 = new LinkedListHT();
System.out.println("lst1 size is " + lst1.size());
lst1.addHead(10);
System.out.println("lst1 size is " + lst1.size());
System.out.println(lst1);
lst1.addHead(20);
lst1.addHead(20);
lst1.addHead(20);
lst1.addHead(20);
lst1.addHead(50);
lst1.addHead(431);
lst1.addHead(57);
System.out.println(lst1);
lst1.addTail(60);
lst1.addTail(70);
lst1.addTail(20);
System.out.println(lst1);
System.out.println("20 is in there " + lst1.count(20));
System.out.println("lst1 size is " + lst1.size());
System.out.println(lst1);
lst1.delHead();
System.out.println(lst1);
lst1.delAll(20);
System.out.println(lst1);
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Normal sum program: " + lst1.sum());
System.out.println(lst1.sumEven());
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
System.out.println();
LinkedListHT lst2 = new LinkedListHT();
lst2.addHead(19);
lst2.addHead(45);
lst2.addHead(12);
lst2.addHead(64);
lst1.addTail2(lst2);
System.out.println(lst1);


//linkedlist class
private Node head = null; private Node tail = null;

public void addHead(int x){
//insert x at head of list
    Node nw = new Node(x);
    if(head == null){
      head = nw; tail = nw;
    }
    else{
     nw.setNext(head);
     head = nw;
    }
}


 public void addTail(int x){ //add at head
    Node nw = new Node(x);
    if(head == null){
        head = nw; tail = nw;
    }
    else{
    tail.setNext(nw);
      tail = nw;
    }

  public void addTail2(LinkedListHT lst){
    Node k = lst.head;
    while (k != null) {
        System.out.println("Now adding " + k.data());
        this.addTail(k.data());
        System.out.println(this);
        k = k.next()
 public void delTail(){
      if(head == tail){
         head = null; tail = null;
        }
        else{
          Node k = head;
          while(k.next() != tail) k = k.next();
          k.setNext(null);
          tail = k;
        }
    }

 public int size(){
        Node k = head;
        int len = 0;
        while(k != null){
              len++; k = k.next();
        }
        return len;
    }
    public void delHead(){
        if(head != null)
            head = head.next();
    }
    public void delAll(int x){
        Node k = head; Node bk = head;
        boolean found = false;
        while(k != null) {
            if(k.data() == x) {
                found = true;
            }
            else{ bk = k; k = k.next();}

            if(found) {
                //System.out.println("found one!");
                if(k == head)
                    head = k.next();
                else {
                      bk.setNext(k.next());
                      k = k.next();
                }
            }
            //System.out.println("first, k is now " + k.data() + " and bk is now " + bk.data());
            //k = k.next();
            //System.out.println("now, k is now " + k.data() + " and bk is now " + bk.data());
            found = false;
        }
    }
    public int sum(){
        Node k = head;
        int a = 0;
        while(k != null){
              a += k.data(); k = k.next();
        }
        return a;
    }
    public int sumEven(){
        Node k = head;
        int a = 0;
        while(k != null){
            if(k.data() % 2 == 0) {
              a += k.data();
            }
             k = k.next();
        }
        return a;
    }

    public int count(int x){
        Node k = head;
        int c = 0;
        while(k != null){
            if(k.data() == x)
              c++;
            k = k.next();
        }
        return c;
    }

  public String toString(){
    if(head == null) return "[]";
    String s = "[";
    Node k = head;
    while(k.next() != null){
        s = s + k.data()+", ";
        k = k.next();
    }
    s = s + k.data()+"]";
    return s;
}

 //Node Class
 private class Node{
    int data;
    Node next;
    public Node(int x){
        data = x; next = null;
    }
    public Node next(){return next;}
    public void setNext(Node p){
        next = p;
    }
    public void set(int x){data = x;}
    public int data(){return data;}
}

 //output
 Now adding 64
 [431, 50, 10, 60, 70]
 Now adding 12
 [431, 50, 10, 60, 70]
 Now adding 45
 [431, 50, 10, 60, 70]
 Now adding 19
 [431, 50, 10, 60, 70]
```

As you can see the problem lies within the addTail2 method.

*****EDIT*****
Problem Solved, my delAll method was deleting the tails reference seeing as though I had deleted a tail with DelAll(20) without an if statement dealing with if the node that was removed was a Tail. Careless on my part. After simply appending delAll with

```
 if(found) {
            //System.out.println("found one!");
            if(k == head) {
                head = k.next();
            }
            else if(k == tail) {
                bk.setNext(null);
                tail = bk;
            }
            else {
                  bk.setNext(k.next());
                  k = k.next();
            }
```

now everything is perfect

Remember kids, when dealing with linkedLists, make sure references to your head/tails is ***ALWAYS*** valid, no matter what situation you're dealing with when modifying the list

Comment: Where's the code for `setNext()`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @shmosel very sorry, added the node class in there

Comment: We probably need to know how `setHead()` is written if the original list was populated with that.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, still getting used to StackOverflow I guess, didnt wanna clutter with too much somewhat disposable info :-)

Comment: Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or at least something that compiles.

Comment: @robert I'm fully aware of those guidelines (which are *just* guidelines, not rules) and posted a sufficient amount of legible code

Comment: @petegoast Please post something which other developers can copy&paste into their IDEs and directly execute. In particular in this case, I took your code and could not reproduce your problem. I think your problem is somewhere else, not in addTail2(). While guidelines are guidelines, there are there for a reason.

Comment: @petegoast People who have questions, especially fundamental questions like "why isn't this method 'working'", are in a poor position to decide what a "sufficient" amount of code is. Your question asks about "this method", but you don't identify it. I, and I expect a number of other people willing to help you, have spent too much of my time trying to guess what the question is from amongst a bunch of code to keep doing it. We ask for executable code because that, at least, can generally be evaluated objectively, i.e., we could ask for "a complete and identifiable question".

Comment: Up to you, petegoast. You can throw incomplete code at us and hope that someone is willing to dig through it and help you. Or you can make it easy to help you by providing the MCVE. Complaining to others that they need to help you even if you don't follow the guidelines is probably not going to help. Good luck anyway.

Comment: In my code below, I had to implement the toString() method of the LinkedListHT. How did you do that?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with these codes. You should just step through the codes to see exactly what is happening.

Comment: @brianbcr666Ray I have added my toString method, this is also something my lecturer provided.

Comment: Again, don't guess. Post something we can directly execute without having to make any modifications ourselves (for example, your code so far doesn't have a complete main() method). Any detail may be important, and you don't know which one it may be, otherwise you wouldn't be asking here in the first place.

Comment: I apologise, I understand from now on exactly how to do post a question when I want the best outcome. Thanks for your patience. I did find the trouble. One of my other methods I had used earlier in the main program must have deleted my tail or something like that.

Comment: Feel free to update your post with your finding - it will help other people to be on the lookout for indirect interactions like such.

Comment: @Lars right now I've just posted the entire program as I've gone through it myself. Once I find the problem I will be sure to edit it and point out exactly where things went wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code as I have constructed it from your submission: This seems to work

```
public class LinkedListHT {
    private Node head = null; 
    private Node tail = null;

    public LinkedListHT() {
        // empty constructor
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
        Node nd = head;
        String separator = "";
        while (nd != null) {
            sb.append(separator);
            sb.append(nd.getData());
            separator = ", ";
            nd = nd.getNext();
        }
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void addHead(int x) {
        //insert x at head of list
        Node nw = new Node(x);
        if(head == null){
            head = nw; tail = nw;
        } else {
            nw.setNext(head);
            head = nw;
        }
    }

    public void addTail(int x){ //add at head
        Node nw = new Node(x);
        if(head == null) {
            head = nw;
            tail = nw;
        } else {
            tail.setNext(nw);
            tail = nw;
        }
}

    public void addTail2(LinkedListHT lst){
        Node k = lst.head;
        while (k != null) {
            System.out.println("Now adding " + k.getData());
            this.addTail(k.getData());
            System.out.println(this);
            k = k.getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

The node object, I made the code a little more in accordance with accepted practices

```
public class Node {
    private int data = 0;
    private Node next = null;

    public Node(int x) {
        data = x;
    }

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node p) {
        next = p;
    }

    public void setData(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

And finally the controller class

```
public class LinkedListTest {

    public LinkedListTest() {
        LinkedListHT lst1 = new LinkedListHT();
        lst1.addHead(431);
        lst1.addHead(50);
        lst1.addHead(10);
        lst1.addHead(60);
        lst1.addHead(70);
        LinkedListHT lst2 = new LinkedListHT();
        lst2.addHead(19);
        lst2.addHead(45);
        lst2.addHead(12);
        lst2.addHead(64);
        lst1.addTail2(lst2);
        System.out.println(lst1);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new LinkedListTest();
    }
}
```

The output

```
Now adding 64
[431, 50, 10, 60, 70, 64]
Now adding 12
[431, 50, 10, 60, 70, 64, 12]
Now adding 45
[431, 50, 10, 60, 70, 64, 12, 45]
Now adding 19
[431, 50, 10, 60, 70, 64, 12, 45, 19]
[431, 50, 10, 60, 70, 64, 12, 45, 19]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. While it doesn't help as I have to keep the node class my lecturer gave me, this will absolutely help me try and find where the clutch differences lie between my code and yours

Comment: Everything I have is pretty much a copy paste from here and it still works, even after using your lecturer's code for `Node` and `toString()`. Is there any other code that you haven't shown us?

Comment: Good to know I'm doing something right, but no not really, the original linkedlist isn't getting updated with the new tails as they're being added in for some reason. Thank you so much though, I know now I should do a lot more work into getting code more 'streamlined' for problems like these before asking questions, thank you for patience I'll work on it myself more tomorrow :)

Comment: You can always use the debugger, or put in more println statements to see how the program flows.

Comment: When I copied just the bare essentials it worked for me as well. I had done other methods within my main program before, which is what I wasn't showing. I understand now the best way to debug. I have grown as a coder and a person :) if you could look at the entire program now I have pasted, maybe you could help me find out where it's going wrong....

Comment: You can't shouldn't use `==` and `!=` with objects, only primitaves. Use the `.equals(Object object)` method instead. And of course override that method in your object.

Comment: Also, in delAll(), you check for the special case that the node being deleted is 'head', but you aren't doing the same thing for 'tail'. I can't run through the code now myself right now, but if it were my code, I'd check my own assumptions at that point; even if it is a false alarm.

Comment: That was the entire problem, thank you so much, I found that out after commenting out each method I was using one by one. Also what did you mean by == or != with objects? I wasn't doing it on an object, I was using it on an object's primitive variable. Is that still frowned upon? Would love to learn more.

Comment: You use `k.next() != tail`. In this case, it works because of the nature of your linked list, but usually you would use `!k.next().equals(tail)` in this case though, I would've used `k.next().next() != null`